# Grafana: No value to text mapping

Tags: grafana

Like you can see in the following screenshot I am trying to map "no value" to text. What I want to achieve is that in the case of "no value" the text "offline" gets displayed. My guess is that "no value" is not the right parameter to map with, but I have no idea whats the right one. I also tryed NaN which doesnt work to.
I would be really happy if someone can point me to the right value here!

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `null` instead of no value.

Also, for your 2nd mapping, you could use range to text. You could use range to text for both your mappings actually..

```
null - null => offline
1 - 1000 => online
```

You might need to save dashboard and refresh it to see changes. It did not update for me without a refresh (using an older version though).

[image]

Comment: Can we set custom colors for each text?